# webpack not working with angular-jquery-timepicker, angular-momentjs, highstock-release, angular-ui-date, ng-file-upload?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, momentjs, highcharts

I've been trying to use  angular-jquery-timepicker, angular-momentjs, highstock-release, angular-ui-date, ng-file-upload with webpack. However, I keep seeing the error like that the app failed to instantiate module angular-jquery-timepicker (and angular-momentjs, highstock-release, angular-ui-date, ng-file-upload). I imported the modules and verified that it's in the vendor.js and vendor.bundle.js. How could I check if the library I use can work properly with webpack? Does any of the modules I listed above can be used with webpack?  Thanks.

ex:
my angular module

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('abcd.sections.content.control.schedule', [
    'abcd.components',
    'ui.timepicker',
  ]);
})();
```

in my vendor.js, I have

```
import 'angular-jquery-timepicker';
```

and in my vendor.bundle.js, I can see

```
/* 521 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    /*global angular */
    /*
     Directive for jQuery UI timepicker (http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/)

     */
    var m = angular.module('ui.timepicker', []);


    m.value('uiTimepickerConfig', {
        'step': 15
    });

    m.directive('uiTimepicker', ['uiTimepickerConfig', '$parse', '$window', function(uiTimepickerConfig, $parse, $window) {
        var moment = $window.moment;

        var isAMoment = function(date) {
            return moment !== undefined && moment.isMoment(date) && date.isValid();
        };
        var isDateOrMoment = function(date) {
            return date !== null && (angular.isDate(date) || isAMoment(date));
        };

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                ngModel: '=',
                baseDate: '=',
                uiTimepicker: '=',
            },
            priority: 1,
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                'use strict';
                var config = angular.copy(uiTimepickerConfig);
                var asMoment = config.asMoment || false;
                delete config.asMoment;

                ngModel.$render = function() {
                    var date = ngModel.$modelValue;
                    if (!angular.isDefined(date)) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (date !== null && date !== '' && !isDateOrMoment(date)) {
                        throw new Error('ng-Model value must be a Date or Moment object - currently it is a ' + typeof date + '.');
                    }
                    if (isAMoment(date)) {
                        date = date.toDate();
                    }
                    if (!element.is(':focus') && !invalidInput()) {
                        element.timepicker('setTime', date);
                    }
                    if(date === null){
                        resetInput();
                    }
                };

                scope.$watch('ngModel', function() {
                    ngModel.$render();
                }, true);

                config.appendTo = config.appendTo || element.parent();

                element.timepicker(
                    angular.extend(
                        config, scope.uiTimepicker ?
                            scope.uiTimepicker :
                            {}
                    )
                );

                var resetInput = function(){
                    element.timepicker('setTime', null);
                };

                var userInput = function() {
                    return element.val().trim();
                };

                var invalidInput = function() {
                    return userInput() && ngModel.$modelValue === null;
                };

                element.on('$destroy', function() {
                    element.timepicker('remove');
                });

                var asDate = function() {
                    var baseDate = ngModel.$modelValue ? ngModel.$modelValue : scope.baseDate;
                    return isAMoment(baseDate) ? baseDate.toDate() : baseDate;
                };

                var asMomentOrDate = function(date) {
                    return asMoment ? moment(date) : date;
                };

                if (element.is('input')) {
                    ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
                        var date = element.timepicker('getTime', asDate());
                        return date ? asMomentOrDate(date) : date;
                    });
                    ngModel.$validators.time = function(modelValue) {
                        return (!attrs.required && !userInput()) ? true : isDateOrMoment(modelValue);
                    };
                } else {
                    element.on('changeTime', function() {
                        scope.$evalAsync(function() {
                            var date = element.timepicker('getTime', asDate());
                            ngModel.$setViewValue(date);
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: Did you make sure, that the `vendor.bundle.js` is loaded and ready before you reference `ui.timepicker` in your module constructor? E.g. you have something like `<script src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>` and **then** `<script src="mymodule.js"></script>`?

Comment: yeah, the `vendor.bundle.js` is loaded. I have
`<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="app.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="upgrade_adapter.bundle.js"></script>`